# Trigram count print

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wanted to print the trigram frequency of a list of text files in a folder.
This is my python code, it doesn't print anything.
Any thoughts on what changes should made ?

```
import nltk
import os
from nltk import trigrams
for fn in os.listdir('folder path where txt files are stored'):
    if os.path.isfile(fn):
        infile = open(fn,"r")
        for line in infile:
            tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
            tokens = [token.lower() for token in tokens if len(token) > 1]
            tri_tokens = trigrams(tokens)
            print [(item, tri_tokens.count(item)) for item in sorted(set(tri_tokens))]
```

Comment: You should check to see that you are getting items into 'tokens' and 'tri_tokens'.

Comment: What is the nltk library? I've never heard of it. and it doesn't load into my vanilla python2.7 install

Comment: nltk = natural language toolkit. Everything here looks fine to me, but we dont know really what the true input is here (other than that you're reading from file), can you provide a more self contained example

Comment: Is it literally not printing anything, or is it printing `[]` for an empty list on each file?  If it is not printing anything, the most likely issue is that `os.listdir()` is somehow not finding the files correctly.  You might want to add a print statement like `print("DEBUG: now reading file '%s'" % fn)`

Comment: @steveha , it doesn't print anything even after putting the Debug print statement you suggested. The path file I use is 'C:\Users\ABC\Downloads\our_data\our_data'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your filename has backslashes in it, you need to use a Python "raw" string:

```
fname = r'C:\Users\ABC\Downloads\our_data\our_data'
```

Alternatively, you should be able to replace the backslashes with forward slashes:

```
fname = 'C:/Users/ABC/Downloads/our_data/our_data'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not going to solve your overall issue, but you should definitely change the following:

```
infile = open(fn,"r")
```

to:

```
with open(fn, "r") as infile:
```

Unless you have additional code that you're not showing, you aren't closing your file descriptors, which can lead to unintended consequences, especially if you're opening a large number of files.

Comment: In CPython, the files will likely be closed automatically when the reference count on the file object drops to zero.  Still it is always best to use `with`.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, still it doesn't print anything. I don't have any additional code. The file path I use is 'C:\Users\ABC\Downloads\our_data\our_data' .